# Insulated gate SCR, does it exist?

Tags: fet, scr

Is there such a thing as an insulated gate SCR or anything fitting that description?

Comment: insulated gate for the power level of SCR became the IGBT.

Comment: Do IGBTs latch?

Comment: LOL    not intentionally

Comment: sensitve gate SCR is probably the closest you'll get. or you could put a mosfet on an SCR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently [MOS-controlled thyristors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS-controlled_thyristor) were commercially available briefly, but were withdrawn due to performance issues.

[image]

The structure looked like this:

[image]

Comment: Spehro, I got very interested when this hit the news in 1983 or 1985.  I had forgotten. Had such great possibilities then

Comment: @Marla I was designing in thyristors in that time period, but must have missed it. Other than the introduction of alternistors I don't think much has changed in 30+ years.

Comment: In the wikipedia article that you linked to there is a mention of a "MOS-gated Thyristor".  I googled this term and interestingly a recent product (2014) from IXYS was ranked high in the results.

Comment: Here is the datasheet for one such device: http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DS100610A(IXHX40N150V1HV).pdf

Comment: @BrianKubera  nice find- and they are actually available (albeit not cheap).

Answer (score 6):

you can make one like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdwri0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I like that Jasen. Not a single component,  but seems like what the OP is wanting.   +1

Comment: I agree with Marla, however note that if you 'tease' the gate you can get a lot of power dissipation in some situations - eg. 400VDC and 100mA SCR trigger current, you could see 40W dissipation in M1 before the SCR turns on.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of SCR.

Standard SCR : turns on at application of gate signal. Stays on in absence of gate signal until anode cathode current falls below threshold current level.

GTO :  Gate Turn Off SCR : SCR can be commanded to turn off under certain conditions.

Insulated Gate Bipolar Transistor :  IGBT : Stays on while gate signal applied.
Turns off when gate signal is removed (regardless of collector current)

Simple description of each,  further search will help based upon key words. .

I don't know of any device available that fits your description

Answer (score 1):

That's it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgGn8z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: As he mentioned Insulated as Explicitly you have made this pulse transformer circuit. Its correct. 

 But his intention is to know about as a single component rather than a circuit.

Comment: @Raj "insulated gate SCR or anything fitting that description", since there is no isolated gate SCR, this circuit is used to trigger SCR in many power applications, other suggested circuits (answers) based on IGBT do need separate PSU and galvanic isolation for each SCR trigger circuit.

Comment: The question asks for *insulated* gate SCR, which I read as "FET-like input" SCR, but this is a concept orthogonal to galvanic *isolation*.